# how to put the select range dialog box onto an excel vba form as a gui control

Tags: excel, vba, user-interface, controls, range

Some built in excel formulas and functions require you to select a range and they give you a gui control to do so.

How can incorporate one of these Range GUI controls into a VBA form to allow the user to select a range?

An example of this Select Range GUI control can be found on the Create New Formula Rule (for Conditional Formatting) below.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called a `RefEdit` control.

You *may* need to enable this by right-clicking the Controls Toolbox and selecting the option for "Additional Controls". Scroll down and check the box for `RefEdit.Ctrl`.  This will add the icon to the Controls Toolbox (it is third from the right, in the second row in my screenshot).

[image]

You *may also* need to enable this from the References in the VBE:

[image]

These controls return an address string based on the range selected by the user.

[image]

**NOTE** This control does not seem to play well if the user form is shown `vbModeless`.  If you don't know what that means, then you don't need to worry about it. A form's default behavior is to `.Show vbModal`, and it should work in that context.  See also [HERE](http://peltiertech.com/using-refedit-controls-in-excel-dialogs/) for other potential pitfalls when using a RefEdit control.

Comment: Thanks David! I don't know but I am interested in what vbModeless means, can you please explain. Also something I find incredibly frustrating about VBA and you maybe able to help is: A lack of object model where I can read through every programming construct even the ones which for some reason don't show up when you click Record Button. Why? This RefEdit Control to select a range. I'd love to see that in a list of all available objects I can manipulate. Another example is a ColorPicker where someone has written code about a Color Gui control. I'd love to know where that is written in MSdoco4XL

Comment: There is no single VBA object model. But the Excel object model should help you out: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194068(v=office.15).aspx). In Excel nearly everything is "recorded" by macro recorder. `vbModeless` displays a form while also allowing the user to interact with Excel application. `vbModal` which is default, does not allow ineraction with the Excel application.

Comment: You may also find this documentation of all [VBA Statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj692812(v=office.15).aspx) useful.

Comment: Also, if this answer has helped solve your problem, do consider [accepting the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: Thanks David, do you know why there is no single object model?

Comment: The simplest answer is probably this: there is a different object model for each application wherein you can use VBA. Of course you may append to this using DLL's or other library references (and you can reference or use the Excel model from within PowerPoint or Outlook and vice versa...), but there is not an "object model" to the *language* itself, there is only an "object model" for the object(s) with which you work.